# VBA deleting name throws object required

Tags: vba, names

I just want to delete a few names that get created every time a querytable gets created. They are all in 3 sheets starting with 0048,0114,0715, so I would just delete all names that start with any of them. However, I get the rejection "object required" in the if clause when I use rName.Delete. Without this, the code runs fine and prints all the names. Also, if I do range(rName).delete it would delete the ranges in the workbook (not what I want, though).

```
Sub delNames()
Dim strStartString(0 To 2) As String

strStartString(0) = "'0048'!mta"
strStartString(1) = "'0114'!mta"
strStartString(2) = "'0715!'mta"

For Each rName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    For Each ss In strStartString
        If rName.Name Like ss & "*" Then
            Debug.Print rName.Name
            rName.Delete
        End If
    Next ss
Next rName
End Sub
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Modifying a collection while looping through it can cause problems.  Try using a for next loop counting back through the names in reverse - `For x = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count to 1 Step -1 : ActiveWorkbook.Names(x).Delete`

Answer (score 0):

Posting Tim's comment as solution

Modifying a collection while looping through it can cause problems. Try using a for next loop counting back through the names in reverse - For x = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count to 1 Step -1 : ActiveWorkbook.Names(x).Delete – Tim Williams 49 mins ago

Comment: you are lucky to have all the names in English alphabets, i encountered a workbook with "_", Japanese and Chinese characters, which macros does not work! in this case, you need to open the 2007+ files with 7zip or rar, open the workbook.xml and remove them manually!